# Using android apis for different versions

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and I am fetching android contacts.

Now I am using statement

```
// Deaclaring desired fileds
        final String[] projection = new String[] { RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                RawContacts._ID, RawContacts.DELETED };

        // Derclaring desired cursor

        final Cursor rawContacts = managedQuery(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection. null, null, null);
```

So it is showing that **managedQuery** has been deprecated in android api 11.So will it work on android api level 11 ot not.

or

If I use the most updated version will it be working on old api versions or not

Comment: Being deprecated doesn't mean it no longer works, it means it's no longer supported, as in updated. Also, you should look into `LoaderManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost identical to the sample code in ContactManager for Android v4.2.2 (API 17), which is the same as v2.2 (API 10) and as far back as the first Sample code package in v2.1 (API 7).  So, yes this will definitely work in much older versions.  And considering that they still include that method call it in the Samples package, the deprecated method should have a long shelf life as well.

Answer (score 0):

It will work on API 11.

Regarding older versions, when writing code you will be prompted with an error/warning if the code can't run in the Android API versions established in your manifest.